# Calling a function that adds £ when over a certain limit?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm looking for a function, preferably, that I can use so that if a product goes over the sale of 4 that another number is added.

So basically if somebody orders 4 lipbalms, they automatically are charged £10 delivery - but if they order less than 4 their delivery is free.

Kind of new to JavaScript. I have been told to use a function, and possibly an IF statement with +=....

Anyone?
Thanks.

Code so far:

```
function costTotal() {
    if (product.selectedIndex != 0 && cost.selectedIndex != 0) {
        var costTotal       = document.getElementById("costTotal");
        var productCount        = product.value;

        var costAmount      = (cost.value).substr(1);
        costTotal.value = "£" + productCount * costAmount;
    }
}
product.onchange    = costTotal;
cost.onchange   = costTotal;
```

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: Hi Carl, I have edited it with the current code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var costAmount      = (cost.value).substr(1);
if(productCount >= 4) {
    costTotal.value = "$" + (productCount * costAmount + 10);
} else {
    costTotal.value = "$" + (productCount * costAmount);
}
```

(if you excuse my use of dollar sign instead of pound sign)

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer your question, but keep in mind there are a number of other factors at play.  Namely that deciding if an order gets free shipping should NOT be done exclusively on the client side.  The client should show it to the user, but the server should be deciding that.

```
//this is the number of lipbalms you have, i'm not sure where you'd really get this value from in your program
var lipBalms = 3;
//this is the shipping cost, which like i said, should be decided by the server
var shippingCost = 0;

//if the user buys 3 or more lipbalms, raise the shipping cost to 10
if (lipBalms >= 3){
    shippingCost = 10;
}
```

Comment: Although it's outside the scope of the question, you have a very good point.  Final calculations and error checking should always be done server side.  Doing it on the client side can make the numbers available to the user faster, but you still need to check the math on the server before letting the transaction go through.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was trying to get across.  It's totally acceptable to update it in real time on the client, you just need to make sure to have the server do the final calculations.  Never trust the client!